# How to center title in default toolbar without custom layout?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-theme, android-styles

I have this Theme and want to center the title in the default toolbar. This means that I have no Toolbar in my XML file. This is what I have tried:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppBaseTheme.Toolbar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppBaseTheme.Toolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="titleCentered">true</item>
</style>
```

Where `<item name="titleCentered">true</item>` doesn't center the title. How to solve this?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, even still, at least not without modifying something somewhere else. That `titleCentered` attribute is from `MaterialToolbar` (which only just recently added that itself), but the default decor in your `ComponentActivity` or `AppCompatActivity` is going to be using the androidx `Toolbar`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for commenting to my question. Then how can I center the title without creating a custom layout?

Comment: I'm not sure what the main goal is. Are you trying to avoid layouts? Or are you trying to avoid changing the default `ActionBar`? If it's the former, you could simply use a `NoActionBar` theme, and create your own `MaterialToolbar` in code. If it's the latter, then something like is shown in the answer below would probably be the preferred solution. If it's both, then you can combine those and use the `setCustomView()` approach with `View`s you've created yourself in code.

Comment: @MikeM. My goal is to just center the title without creating a Toolbar in code. So, yes, trying to avoid layouts. I don't want to create my own MaterialToolbar. So is there any other option. Somehow find the Title and set a gravity center?

Comment: Technically, yes, there are ways to do that, but you're venturing into hacky, unstable-solution territory. There is no existing, explicit method or API to specifically center an `ActionBar`'s title, so anything we do might be more prone to break in the wild. I could probably put together an example or two after a while, if you'd still want to try it.

Comment: @MikeM. YES, I really want to try it. Please add it as an answer. THANK YOU!

Comment: I don't post answers here anymore, but here are some ideas for you: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jg2lg8rcn_Gbhps8vviyFRWYr76I4pYj/view?usp=sharing. I assumed you're cool with Kotlin, judging from some of your previous questions, but lemme know if anything's unclear.

Comment: I'm just looking at your solutions.

Comment: @MikeM. I don't have any Toolbar in my XML file so I can find it. I try to use the other solutions. I'm sorry for this stupid question, but can I use/call `val Toolbar.titleViewByIteration: TextView?....`?

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for sharing so much information. But one think I don't understand. Since I have **no** Toolbar in my layout file, I cannot use any findViewById() to find that, right? So this cannot be used either `val title = toolbar.titleViewByIteration`.

Comment: `Activity`'s `findViewById()` method is just a convenience for its `Window`s `findViewById()` method; i.e., it just relays that call directly to the `Window`'s same method. The `Window` holds everything in your app's UI for that `Activity`, including the decor `View`s that are provided automatically, like the default `ActionBar`. So, even though your content is only inside child of the overall `Activity` content, `findViewById()` is searching everything "above" it in the hierarchy, too. Make sense?

Comment: It makes sense and it worked. Thank you so much!! But when the home/back button is activated, the text is not centered :| Is centered only when the ( < ) button is not present.

Comment: Yeah, remember when I said this is "hacky, unstable-solution territory"? :-)

Comment: Yes, you were right. I'll try to find another hacky :) Thank you so much again!'

Comment: @MikeM. May I ask you why would you not prefer to add that as an answer? Thanks again.

Comment: I just don't post answers here in general anymore, for various reasons. Nothing against you personally, or anything. :-)

Comment: @MikeM. I see. I would want to thank you again on my behalf, for taking the time to help folks for no reward ;) This is very rare.

Comment: No problem. You caught me on a good day. ;-) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**In your Activity, in your onCreate()**

```
methodgetSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM;
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.main_layout);
```

**main_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```